# Bad output of pdfcairo terminal

Tags: pdf, gnuplot

I see very poor quality of pdfcairo terminal on latest gnuplot 5.2. My very simple script to test is:

```
reset
set terminal pdfcairo font ", 12"
set output 'graph.pdf' 

set samples 10000
unset key

plot sin(x**2) w l

reset
set term wxt
set out
```

The out pdf is:
[I did maximal zoom in pdf viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVPtO.png)

One can see strange jags. Picture goes even worse if we increase number of samples. It is very strange to me, as I thought curve shoud became more smooth with increasing number of samples.

The same behavior is observed when using export to pdf from wxt terminal. But if I set qt terminal and then make export to pdf I get the output curve much better with the same `set samples 10000`:
[Not ideal, but much much better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdKwM.png)

What is going on? Lack of antialiasing in pdfcairo terminal?

**EDIT**

I found discussion about the same issue [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/discussion/5925/thread/61d4c4d6/). One can take script from that thread and change `samples` to higher value, say 10000. This leads to "stepwise" lines instead of smooth curves when we zoom-in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some artefact of the line endings and joins (triggered by the mitering effect of the default `butt` style) of the elementary line segments within the plot due to finite line width. In order to mitigate this, it seems to help to use:

```
set terminal pdfcairo rounded font ",12"
```

i.e., to prescribe `round`ed line endings/joins instead of the default `butt`.

Comment: Yes, this might be a solution. Thanks!